# How can I make Swig correctly wrap a char* buffer that is modified in C as a Java Something-or-other?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I am trying to wrap some legacy code for use in Java and I was quite happy to see that Swig was able to handle the header file and it generate a great wrapper that almost works.  Now I am looking for the deep magic that will make it really work.

In C I have a function that looks like this

```
DLL_IMPORT int DustyVoodoo(char *buff, int len,  char *curse);
```

This integer returned by this function is an error code in case it fails. The arguments are

- `buff` is a character buffer
- `len` is the length of the data in the buffer
- `curse` the another character buffer that contains the result of calling DustyVoodoo

So, you can see where this is going, the result is actually coming back via the third argument.  Also `len` is confusing since it may be the length of both buffers, they are always allocated as being the same size in calling code but given what `DustyVoodoo` does I don't think that they need be the same.  To be safe both buffers should be the same size in practice, say 512 chars.

The C code generated for the binding is as follows:

```
SWIGEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_pemapiJNI_DustyVoodoo(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jstring 

jarg1, jint jarg2, jstring jarg3) {
  jint jresult = 0 ;
  char *arg1 = (char *) 0 ;
  int arg2 ;
  char *arg3 = (char *) 0 ;
  int result;

  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  arg1 = 0;
  if (jarg1) {
    arg1 = (char *)(*jenv)->GetStringUTFChars(jenv, jarg1, 0);
    if (!arg1) return 0;
  }
  arg2 = (int)jarg2; 
  arg3 = 0;
  if (jarg3) {
    arg3 = (char *)(*jenv)->GetStringUTFChars(jenv, jarg3, 0);
    if (!arg3) return 0;
  }
  result = (int)PemnEncrypt(arg1,arg2,arg3);
  jresult = (jint)result; 
  if (arg1) (*jenv)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jenv, jarg1, (const char *)arg1);
  if (arg3) (*jenv)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jenv, jarg3, (const char *)arg3);
  return jresult;
}
```

It is correct for what it does; however, it misses the fact that `cursed` is not just an input, it is altered by the function and should be returned as an output.  It also does not know that the java Strings are really buffers and should be backed by a suitably sized array.

I think that Swig can do the right thing here, I just can't figure out from the documentation how to tell Swig what it needs to know.  Any typemap masers in the house?

Comment: Just a funny aside, I am googeling this myself and was so happy to see a stack overflow article that exactly sounded like what I needed.  It was my own, yet unanswered, question.  30 minutes to the top of google, not bad.

Comment: 30 minutes? It's usually faster ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas for the nudge in the correct direction.  The solution to this was to create a custom typemap that uses a StringBuffer to get the result back.  I found the code in the `examples/java/typemap` directory of the SWIG install.  I must have overlooked that before while I was searching.

I have attached the example code below, I am presently using the alternative approach suggested. However, the first approach of using the BYTE typemap wil require some changes in my Java code but might actually make more sense in the long run.

Thanks for the help, and now I get to see if I can accept my own answer...

```
/* File : example.i */
%module example
%{
/*
   example of a function that returns a value in the char * argument
   normally used like:

   char buf[bigenough];
   f1(buf);
*/

void f1(char *s) {
  if(s != NULL) {
    sprintf(s, "hello world");
  }
}

void f2(char *s) {
  f1(s);
}

void f3(char *s) {
  f1(s);
}

%}

/* default behaviour is that of input arg, Java cannot return a value in a 
 * string argument, so any changes made by f1(char*) will not be seen in the Java
 * string passed to the f1 function.
*/
void f1(char *s);

%include various.i

/* use the BYTE argout typemap to get around this. Changes in the string by 
 * f2 can be seen in Java. */
void f2(char *BYTE);



/* Alternative approach uses a StringBuffer typemap for argout */

/* Define the types to use in the generated JNI C code and Java code */
%typemap(jni) char *SBUF "jobject"
%typemap(jtype) char *SBUF "StringBuffer"
%typemap(jstype) char *SBUF "StringBuffer"

/* How to convert Java(JNI) type to requested C type */
%typemap(in) char *SBUF {

  $1 = NULL;
  if($input != NULL) {
    /* Get the String from the StringBuffer */
    jmethodID setLengthID;
    jclass sbufClass = (*jenv)->GetObjectClass(jenv, $input);
    jmethodID toStringID = (*jenv)->GetMethodID(jenv, sbufClass, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring js = (jstring) (*jenv)->CallObjectMethod(jenv, $input, toStringID);

    /* Convert the String to a C string */
    const char *pCharStr = (*jenv)->GetStringUTFChars(jenv, js, 0);

    /* Take a copy of the C string as the typemap is for a non const C string */
    jmethodID capacityID = (*jenv)->GetMethodID(jenv, sbufClass, "capacity", "()I");
    jint capacity = (*jenv)->CallIntMethod(jenv, $input, capacityID);
    $1 = (char *) malloc(capacity+1);
    strcpy($1, pCharStr);

    /* Release the UTF string we obtained with GetStringUTFChars */
    (*jenv)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jenv,  js, pCharStr);

    /* Zero the original StringBuffer, so we can replace it with the result */
    setLengthID = (*jenv)->GetMethodID(jenv, sbufClass, "setLength", "(I)V");
    (*jenv)->CallVoidMethod(jenv, $input, setLengthID, (jint) 0);
  }
}

/* How to convert the C type to the Java(JNI) type */
%typemap(argout) char *SBUF {

  if($1 != NULL) {
    /* Append the result to the empty StringBuffer */
    jstring newString = (*jenv)->NewStringUTF(jenv, $1);
    jclass sbufClass = (*jenv)->GetObjectClass(jenv, $input);
    jmethodID appendStringID = (*jenv)->GetMethodID(jenv, sbufClass, "append", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;");
    (*jenv)->CallObjectMethod(jenv, $input, appendStringID, newString);

    /* Clean up the string object, no longer needed */
    free($1);
    $1 = NULL;
  }  
}
/* Prevent the default freearg typemap from being used */
%typemap(freearg) char *SBUF ""

/* Convert the jstype to jtype typemap type */
%typemap(javain) char *SBUF "$javainput"

/* apply the new typemap to our function */
void f3(char *SBUF);
```

Comment: It won't let me accept my own answer until tomorrow, oh well.  Now we know.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps [this part](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#input_output_parameters) of the SWIG documentation is helpful:

> A common problem in some C programs is handling parameters passed as simple pointers or references. For example:
>
> ```
> void add(int x, int y, int *result) {
>     *result = x + y;
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The typemaps.i library file will help in these situations. For example:
>
> ```
> %module example
> %include "typemaps.i"
>
> void add(int, int, int *OUTPUT);
> ```

There's also a [section on wrapping arrays](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#c_arrays).

I'm sorry this isn't a ready-made, complete answer. SWIG is mind-bending at times.

Comment: SWIG is mind bending, I will let you know how it works out later this weekend.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple and dumb workaround if you are as lazy as I am and if you have the liberty to change the prototype of C/C++ function slightly. 
Change the type of your parameter ( in your interface file) to unsigned char* instead of char* and then SWIG maps it to SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char :-) instead of String in Java

Comment: Unfortunately SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char gives just a character when dereferenced so it is no good - sorry for misleading. By the way I am wondering - if in above example if I have to use a ByteBuffer instead of StringBuffer then what are the changes in typemap ? Can someone comment on that ?