# How to use a java.nio.ByteBuffer return from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

This is almost a  repeat of question in [How can I make Swig correctly wrap a char* buffer that is modified in C as a Java Something-or-other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740068/how-can-i-make-swig-correctly-wrap-a-char-buffer-that-is-modified-in-c-as-a-jav) ...
Instead of Stringbuffer if I were to use a bytebuffer, what would be the change in the typemap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together an example of how you might do this using the following header file/function as a test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void foo(char *buf, int len) {
  while(len--)
    putchar(*buf++);
}
```

My solution was to modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584599/pass-an-array-to-a-wrapped-function-as-pointersize-or-range/11584600#11584600) such that the proxy takes a `ByteBuffer` and converts it into a `byte[]` for us to pass to the JNI code, which then converts it into a pointer + length combination for us.

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(jtype) (char *buf, int len) "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) (char *buf, int len) "java.nio.ByteBuffer"
%typemap(jni) (char *buf, int len) "jbyteArray"
%typemap(javain,pre="    byte[] temp$javainput = new byte[$javainput.capacity()];"
                    "    $javainput.get(temp$javainput);")
        (char *buf, int len) "temp$javainput"

%typemap(in,numinputs=1) (char *buf, int len) {
  $1 = JCALL2(GetByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, NULL);
  $2 = JCALL1(GetArrayLength, jenv, $input);
}

%typemap(freearg) (const signed char *arr, size_t sz) {
  // Or use  0 instead of ABORT to keep changes if it was a copy
  JCALL3(ReleaseByteArrayElements, jenv, $input, $1, JNI_ABORT); 
}

%include "test.h"
```

The new bit here is in the javain typemap, allocating a temporary `byte[]` and then using `get` to fill it. There is actually an `array()` function that if the `ByteBuffer` you're using supports you should use instead, i.e. the typemap should be just:

```
%typemap(javain) (char *buf, int len) "$javainput.array()"
```

if your implementation supports it (the method is optional and may throw `UnsuportedOperationException`).

In actual fact this can be simplified further with SWIG 2.0, from the previous referenced question since we are expecting the type to *always* be `byte` we can use a built int typemap from SWIG 2.0 to simplify our interface which now becomes:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (char *buf, int len) }
%typemap(javain) (char *buf, int len) "$javainput.array()"
%typemap(jstype) (char *buf, int len) "java.nio.ByteBuffer"

%include "test.h"
```

I tested all three versions of this with the following Java:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    byte value[] = "hello world\n".getBytes();
    java.nio.ByteBuffer buf = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(value);
    test.foo(buf);
  }
}
```

To be safe with the possibly unsupported `array()` what you probably want to do is add a try/catch in a function with a pragma:

```
%pragma(java) modulecode = %{
  private static byte[] buf2bytearr(java.nio.ByteBuffer buf) {
    try {
      return buf.array();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
      byte arr[] = new byte[buf.capacity()];
      buf.get(arr);
      return arr;
    }
  }
%}
```

and then modify the typemap to use that:

```
%typemap(javain) (char *buf, int len) "buf2bytearr($javainput)"
```

Comment: Flexo - Thank you so much  - I have a function with four arguments - I created interface definition for that but ran into trouble. am attaching my interface which offcourse does not work in another question that should give you an idea of what I am up to