# SWIG - creating a typemap for function with four arguments that passes a bytearray

Tags: java, c++, byte, swig

This is a follow-up of the question [How to use a ByteBuffer return from C++ to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618267/how-to-use-a-bytebuffer-return-from-c-to-java) - I will acknowledge Flexo for his relentless support so far - I guess I just am not getting hang of typemaps yet... :-(

I have a C function with four arguments as follows, where  the third and fourth arguments are passed by reference

```
extern "C" int foo(const char* passByValText, const int passbyValLen, 
             unsigned char* retTextByRef, int *retTextLen)
```

The Calling Java Wrapper function needs to look something like this

```
int foo(String passByValText, int passbyValLen, byte[] retBuf, SWIGTYPE_p_int retTextLen);
```

Alternatively it could be

```
int foo(String passByValText, int passbyValLen, ByteBuffer retBuf, SWIGTYPE_p_int retTextLen);
```

I can share an apology for a typemap that I wrote - but basically that might confuse matters even more ... so I am keeping this a clean slate ..

below is example code on c side

```
extern "C" int foo (const char* passByValText, const int passbyValLen, char *retTextByRef, int *retTextLen){
    // binary value stuffed in the retTextByRef. In real program I compute this
    unsigned char someText[10]={0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x00};    
    memcpy(cipherText,someText,9);
    // I set the length of the value I stuffed into the buffer in c program
    *cipherLen=9;
return 0;
```

}

And the Java program that calls this c function

```
class Caller{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Define the parameter to pass by reference!!
    SWIGTYPE_p_int retTextLen=MYMODULE.new_intp();

    //Create a Java Wrapper Instance 
    JavaWrapClass myWrap=new JavaWrapClass();

    StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer(50);
    int retTextLenVal=0;
    myWrap.foo("PASSED-STRING-BY-VALUE", 24, sBuf, retTextLen);
    retTextLenVal= MYMODULE.intp_value(retTextLen);
    System.out.println("JAVA :: got length "+ retTextLenVal);
    System.out.println("JAVA :: got BUFFER "+ sBuf);
    }
}
```

Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: This is definitely possible and I'll give an answer, but it would be helpful if you can clarify the question a bit: 1. `passbyValLen` is the length of `passByValText` right? 2. `retText` is an output, but does it relate to `retCode`? 3. do you know the length of `retBuf` before calling? Is it the same as one of the inputs or something predictable? 4. How does `retCode` relate to the returned `int`? My instinct would be to merge them and use exceptions for error and at most a single returned int. I think the ideal clarification would be a "toy" example of how you might implement and use this.

Comment: Yes Flexo you're right - The Java code passes passByValText   and  passbyValLen is the length of passByValText. Also (I changed the names to be more obvious now in above function) the retTextLen is the length of the reurned value from C code retBuf. ..... a BIG THANKS in advance

Comment: You don't need to make an instance of `JavaWrapClass` usually - `foo` is static by default.

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following header to test:

```
static int foo(const char *passByValText, const int passByValLen,
               unsigned char *retTextByRef, int *retTextLen) {
  *retTextLen = passByValLen;
  if (retTextByRef) {
    memcpy(retTextByRef, passByValText, passByValLen);
  }
  return NULL == retTextByRef;
}
```

I then put together the simplest (e.g. least custom typemaps) SWIG interface I could to wrap this function sensibly:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (const char *passByValText, const int passByValLen) };
// Use String instead of byte[] for input as requested in Q:
%typemap(jstype) (const char *passByValText, const int passByValLen) "String"
%typemap(javain) (const char *passByValText, const int passByValLen) "$javainput.getBytes()"

%include <arrays_java.i>

// Force unsigned char array to be byte[] in Java:
%apply signed char[]  { unsigned char *retTextByRef };

%include <typemaps.i>

// Use the OUTPUT typemap - it passes an array with only one element
// could also use cpointers.i if you prefer
%apply int *OUTPUT { int *retTextLen };

%include "test.h"
```

Which ends up exposing the function `foo` as a function that takes three inputs - a `String`, a `byte[]` for the output array and an `int[]` for the output `int`.

This allowed me to write:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    byte arr[] = new byte[100];
    int sz[] = {100};
    test.foo("Hello world", arr, sz);
    System.out.println(new String(arr, 0 , sz[0]));    
  }
}
```

Which worked as expected when tested. The typemaps in arrays_java.i reject `null` arrays, so the `if` in the sample I wrote can't be used to query the output size.

If you want to use a `StringBuffer` instead of a `byte[]` the simplest solution is to use `%pragma` to generate an overload in Java:

```
%pragma(java) modulecode = %{
  public static int foo(String in, StringBuffer out) {
    int sz[] = {out.capacity()};
    byte ret[] = new byte[out.capacity()];
    final int v = test.foo(in, ret, sz);
    // Or whatever your preferred semantics are: 
    out.replace(0, sz[0], new String(ret, 0, sz[0]));
    return v;
  }
%}
```

Comment: I can expand on this if you want to show an alternative typemap for allowing `null` arrays or using `%pointer_class` instead of the output type I used. I can also add an example using `StringBuffer` if you wanted.

Comment: Flexo -  a HUGE thanks for all this help !!!!! - Whats a good place ( online/ book)  to learn typemaps and have a  definitive reference to  syntax for typemaps ?

Comment: @YogeshDevi I've not read any books on SWIG personally. (I did toy with the idea of writing one). Anyway the official documentation is usually pretty good, if a little daunting at first. ([Java specific](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html) and [typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Typemaps.html) being two important ones). Shameless plug: I've answered [quite a lot of SWIG questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:168175+[swig]) in the past that might be interesting reading, they pretty much all have real tested source code.