# SWIG wrap a c++ string into a byte[] in java

Tags: java, c++, swig

swig.i

```
%typemap(jtype) bool foo "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) bool foo "byte[]"
%typemap(jni) bool foo "jbyteArray"
%typemap(javaout) bool foo { return $jnicall; }
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) std::string& out (std::string temp) "$1=&temp;"
%typemap(argout) std::string& out {
  $result = JCALL1(NewByteArray, jenv, $1->size());
  JCALL4(SetByteArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, $1->size(), (const jbyte*)$1->c_str());
}
// Optional: return NULL if the function returned false
%typemap(out) bool foo ""

%inline %{
struct Bar {
  bool foo(std::string& out) {
    std::string s;
    s.push_back('H');
    s.push_back('o');
    s.push_back(0);
    s.push_back('l');
    s.push_back('a');
    out = s;
    return true;
  }
};
%}
```

Java

```
public byte[] foo() { return NativeISecurityProviderJNI.Bar_foo(swigCPtr, this); }
```

Till here everything fine, but what I am trying to get is this java return (byte[]) as an argument.
like

```
public void foo(byte[] example) {}
```

I've tried a lot of possible modifications in order to get that, but there is no way and I've ran out of imagination.
I would appreciate whatever suggestion. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique at [Correct way to interact with arrays using SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497175/correct-way-to-interact-with-arrays-using-swig) likely applies. The technique is documented at [24.8.5 Binary data vs Strings](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#c_arrays).