# How to use correctly use Swig pointer for array mathematics

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, swig

I am learning to use Swig so I can implement a C/C++ to Java interface for a large project. I have started simple.

first, I have an Add function in C:

```
//taken from swig 3.0 samples directory 
void add(int* x, int* y, int* result)
{
    *result = *x + *y

}
```

Next, I have the swig definition:

```
%module example
%include "typemaps.i"
void add(int *INPUT, int *INPUT, int *OUTPUT);

//or alternatively. version #2:
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply int *INPUT {int *x, int *y};
%apply int *OUTPUT {int *r};
void add2(int *x, int *y, int *r);
```

Next, the Java program:

```
System.out.println("Trying the typemap library");
int[] r = {0};
example.add(37,42,r);
System.out.println("     37 + 42 = " + r[0]);

//or alternatively. version #2
example.add2(37,42,r);
System.out.println("     37 + 42 = " + r[0]);
```

Now, my problem is: In Java, I want to be able to add all the variables in from an actual array (and not just single values, like 37 or 42). I want to do this using say, byte[]. For example,

```
byte[] x = new byte[100];
byte[] y = new byte[100];
byte[] r = new byte[100];
```

or

```
Byte x = new Byte("100");
Byte y = new Byte("100");
Byte r = new Byte("100");
```

How do I assign these java byte arrays or byte objects to the C/C++ function that I just wrapped, while making sure that the both sides of the code (java and C/C++) are aware of the array size? I want the wrapped function in C/C++ to be able to add, say, 100 elements.

Comment: And my comment was wrong, should be `*result = *x + *y;`

Comment: @nikk, C and C++ have significant overlap, but each has features and restrictions that the other does not.  In almost all cases, SO questions are about one or the other, not both, and question and answers are all much clearer if you specify.  Your particular case is no different, in part because JNI has a slightly different interfaces for C and C++.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497175/correct-way-to-interact-with-arrays-using-swig

Comment: Do make your life simpler by using Java `byte` and `byte[]` in conjunction with JNI, rather than `Byte` and `Byte[]`, unless you need to accommodate the possibility of nulls.