# Swig: pass byte array in Java to C

Tags: java, c, arrays, java-native-interface, swig

I am trying to create Java implementation for passing byte [] to C using Swig.

Swig:

```
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply(char *STRING, int LENGTH) { (char *buff, int len) }; 
%inline {
   typedef struct {
        char*         buff;        
        int           len;  
  } workit_t;
}
```

In my generated java class (workit_t.java), the parameter buff is a String, instead of a byte [].

Java:

```
public void setBuff(String value){
 ... 
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my swig definition?

When I write a simple swig definition with no struct, I get the desired type of parameter.

Swig:

```
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply(char *STRING, int LENGTH) { (char *buff1, int *len1) };
```

Java:

```
public static void Mathit(byte[] buff1, byte[] buff2) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have been able to get it right.

Before:

```
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply(char *STRING, int LENGTH) { (char *buff, int len) }; 
%inline {
   typedef struct {
        char*         buff;        
        int           len;  
  } workit_t;
}
```

Now:

```
%include various.i                    
%apply char *BYTE { char *buff };  //map a Java byte[] array to a C char array
%inline {
   typedef struct {
        char*         buff;        
        int           len;  
   } workit_t;
}
```

Or:

```
%include various.i                    
%apply char *NIOBUFFER { char *buff }; //map Java nio buffers to C char array
%inline {
   typedef struct {
        char*         buff;        
        int           len;  
   } workit_t;
}
```